# transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug on stuck

Tags: java, android, compiler-optimization

Good morning,
i'm facing an issue on Android Studio when compiling my app. I don't get any output error about **app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug** while building, it simply gets on stuck and runs for too much time.

I have moved my project recently to **AndroidX.**

Gradle sync works fine, so i guess it's a compilation problem, i have tried also by adding multidex but it doesn't work.

Here there is my **app.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.package"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 7
    versionName "1.4"
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    multiDexEnabled true
}

dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

lintOptions {
    disable "ResAuto", "MissingTranslation", "OnClick", "ExtraTranslation"
    // checkReleaseBuilds false
    // abortOnError false

}
aaptOptions {
    additionalParameters "--shared-lib", "-I", "/example/example/apk.apk"
}

useLibrary 'android.test.runner'
useLibrary 'android.test.base'


}

dependencies {
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha02'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-alpha3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha03'
implementation'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

Any suggestion? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you have an Application.java file, please share that if then create it and extend it with MultidexApplication

Answer (score 0):

just remove both 'build' folder in /YourApp and /YourApp/app
and restart with `File > Invalidate Caches/Restart`

Or 
Open terminal and in /YourApp dir. run below command.
`./gradlew clean`

If above both solution not works then please update you Java version from 7 to 8.
You can see [this](https://github.com/Shopify/mobile-buy-sdk-android/issues/549#issuecomment-394636226) answer for ref.